# How can I get translated path aliases for a custom language switcher?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

The Drupal 8 standard "Language switcher" dropdown does not give me what I need. 
What I need is to break everything apart into groups and subgroups, in a div, and have custom text for each Language, some of which are custom languages.

As ugly as my code is, I'm almost there, but I'm getting a node, instead of the actual page.

if I click on U.S. Spanish, I get: 
http://website.com/es-us/node/123
but I want: 
http://website.com/es-us/contactenos

if I click on U.S. English, I get 
http://website.com/en-us/node/123
but I want: 
http://website.com/en-us/contact-us

(note the difference in URL alias, by language)

I've found this page, and used it as my starting point: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multilingual/enable-language-negotiation

As I attempt to understand how I might do it, I have in my themename.theme:

```
<?php

/**
* Implements hook_preprocess_page().
*
* @param $vars
*/
function themename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
 $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
// not used yet... 
$language = $vars['language']->getId();

  $fr_ca = '';
  $en_ca = '';
  $en_us = '';
  $es_us = '';
  $en_gb = '';

  $vars['en_us'] = '/en-us' . $current_path;
  $vars['es_us'] = '/es-us' . $current_path;
  $vars['en_ca'] = '/en-ca' . $current_path;
  $vars['fr_ca'] = '/fr-ca' . $current_path;
  $vars['en_gb'] = '/en-gb' . $current_path;
 }
```

Then I was going to hardcode into the page.tpl.twig (for now, while I learn) something similar to:

```
<div class="region">
    <h1>Americas</h1>
    <div class="country">
      <h2>U.S.</h2>
      <a class="lang-switcher" href="{{ en_us }}">English</a>
      <a class="lang-switcher" href="{{ es_us }}">Español</a>
     </div>
     <div class="country">
       <h2>Canada</h2>
      <a class="lang-switcher" href="{{ en_ca }}">English</a>
      <a class="lang-switcher" href="{{ fr_ca }}">Francais</a>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="region">
   <h1>Europe</h1>
  <div class="country">
    <!-- ETCETERA -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do this for a more experienced coder. But for now, I'm hoping I can get the alias in there.

I can't use **"$current_uri = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();"**

Because that is different for each page... For example, "contactenos" in Spanish versus "contact-us" in English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you can do what you want with `Url` options and a language object like following.

```
// Get all activated languages.
$languages = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguages();

foreach ($languages as $language) {

  // Get the current URL in each language.
  $url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<current>')
    ->setOption('language', $language)->toString();

  // And add it to a custom array.
  $variables['my_langswitch'][$language->getId()] = $url;
}
```

But as I already said in the comments to your question, this should actually be put in a custom block. And since it's all just about a little bit of changing markup I'd even go for JavaScript here and stick to the built-in language switcher. Also as I'm not sure how above works with caching enabled.

---

If you prefer getting the paths one-by-one, get a language object first and then use that to get the path alias.

```
// Get Swedish language
if ($sv_language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguage('sv')) {

  // Get Swedish URL.
  $sv_url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<current>')
    ->setOption('language', $sv_language)->toString();

  // Add it as custom variable.
  $variables['sv_url'] = $sv_url;
}
```